# Displaying small sets of dynamic data without listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

Listviews are great for displaying dynamic data, but it is a lot of overhead if I only want to display dynamic data that I don't expect to use more than two or three views at most.

What is the best practice for adding views to a layout based on a very small dynamic data set?

My current method is to create an empty LinearLayout container, and dynamically adding textview(s) and imageview(s) to it programatically. My data is being obtained through a loader, and the issue is that the android lifecycle causes my layout to add multiple views of the same data.

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way of adding data?

Comment: Well if you problem about Activity lifecycle, you can check if your LinearLayout has child or not before adding the Views. You can use if(linearLayout.getChildCount()>0) return; //already has Views inside

Comment: Create a LinearLayout, inflate a child layout and add to the LinearLayout using Loop..

Comment: Duh! Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!